# Access matrix element in condition

Tags: matlab, profiler

I'm trying to reduce the computational time of my MatLab code. For this I use the [MatLab profiler](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html).

In some functions I was in the same situation. I loop over a grid (a 2D matrix) and I test if each cell has (or not) some values (two each time). And the condition takes a long time. Most of the time spends in those functions.

Here is an example from my code:

```
  time      Calls    line
                      16   function tGrid=some_compute(grid, tGrid, trans)
  0.005       125     17     global depth width tWidth 
                      18
< 0.001       125     19     for i=1:depth 
  0.022    125000     20       for j=1:width 
  2.270  37500000     21         if (grid(i, j)~=0 && grid(i, j)~=1) 
                      22
                      23           % Get the transformed coordinates of the current cell
  0.864     79997     24           [x, y]=get_trans(trans, i, j); 
                      25
  0.006     79997     26           if (x~=-1 && y~=-1) 
  0.006     79992     27             tGrid(x, y)=grid(i, j); 
  0.004     79992     28           end % If x~=-1 && y~=-1 
  0.004     79997     29         end % If grid~=0 && grid~=1 
  1.933  37500000     30       end % For j=width 
  0.008    125000     31     end % For i=depth 
                      32
< 0.001       125     33   end
```

This function takes a total of 5.24s for 125 calls.

As we can see, it's the line 21 who take the more time to execute. While the the `grid(i, j)` is accessed twice in the condition, and is also used in line 27, I guessed by storing it in a variable before, it will speed-up my code.

So, I did this simple modification:

```
  time      Calls    line
                      16   function tGrid=some_compute(grid, tGrid, trans)
  0.005       125     17     global depth width tWidth
                      18
< 0.001       125     19     for i=1:depth
  0.021    125000     20       for j=1:width
  2.062  37500000     21         val=grid(i, j);
  1.681  37500000     22         if (val~=0 && val~=1)
                      23
                      24           % Get the transformed coordinates of the current cell
  0.793     79997     25           [x, y]=get_trans(trans, i, j);
                      26
  0.005     79997     27           if (x~=-1 && y~=-1)
  0.005     79992     28             tGrid(x, y)=val;
  0.004     79992     29           end % If x~=-1 && y~=-1
  0.004     79997     30         end % If grid~=0 && grid~=1
  1.731  37500000     31       end % For j=width
  0.007    125000     32     end % For i=depth
                      33
< 0.001       125     34   end
```

And now, this function takes a total of 6.32s for 125 calls.

As we can see, getting the value of the cell take as much time as getting it twice and compare it to two values. And the if, line 22, is as much slow as in the first version. I don't understand why.

Comment: Just two comments for speed improvement: (1) Changing the order of the loops will speed up this code significantly (as mentioned in the answer below), please try that again, it does make a difference. (2) Don't use `global` if you can avoid it. Here, you should be looping `for i=1:size(grid,2); for j=1:size(grid,1);`. -- If you're looking for help to optimize your code, post a [mre].

Comment: I swaped the loops again, and it really changed nothing!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> getting the value of the cell take as much time as getting it twice and compare it to two values. [...] I don't understand why.

This is because your code is run under a JIT (just-in-time compiler). This compiler optimizes your code. Though it's not documented how exactly it works and what kind of optimizations are implemented, from your experiment it seems clear that `grid(i, j)~=0 && grid(i, j)~=1` is optimized to only fetch the value `grid(i,j)` once.

Comment: Thanks. But if *T* is the time for fetching the value and doing the two comparisons (from the first version), and *t1* and *t2*, respectivly, the time for fetcing the value and the time for doing the two comparisons (in the second version). Why *T* is not almost equal to *t1 + t2*?

Comment: @Phantom: You are adding a variable assignment, which does cost a bit of time. This cannot be optimized away because you use that variable again later. (I don’t know if it would be optimized away if it weren’t used, just that it cannot be optimized away in this case.)

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell you what exactly is going on, because I don't know how the underlying MATLAB libraries are implemented. However, there is a possible reason for the presented results.

If I didn't miscalculate, you are using a **dense** 1000x300 matrix, which is an array of 300.000 floating-point numbers.

From this line

```
2.062  37500000     21         val=grid(i, j);
```

you can calculate that a single execution takes around 55 nanoseconds (time / calls * 10^9) which is quite a lot for a simple data-access. If you have a 2GHz Processor, a processing cycle takes 0,5 nanoseconds. That would be 110 cycles. However, since you are using a huge dense matrix you are probably facing a lot of cache misses here. To be sure, reduce the matrix size drastically (start with 40x12) and calculate the time per execution. It should get down to around 1-2 nanoseconds if you have a cache miss problem.

In case cache misses are truly the problem, I fear there is not really an easy solution to your problem since it requires reorganization of your data in a memory friendly manner. The fact that Matlab is a scripting language doesn't make it easier because you have no compiler that performs optimizations for you.  You can try switching the inner and outer loop and hope that the memory access pattern gets better.

Greetings

Comment: I saw in an other post that in MatLab matrix are stored in column major. So I already try to switch the loops. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Column major is pretty much standard in all linear algebra libs I think, because it is advantageous for vectorization. Which results did you get by switching the loops? Did it get better? And have you tried what happens if you reduce the matrix size?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the end. It changed nothing to switch the loop. It will be very complex to create consistant data to reproduce a similar computation on smaller grid

Comment: I am not entirely sure if it is really a cache problem, but the factor of around 100 is quite suspicious in this context. You can try to use a cache profiler on your Matlab script. However, I don't know if there is one for Matlab, you have to search for that. You can also check resources on optimizing Matlab code in general. Maybe there are some good tips that might help. Additionally, branches (if) in the innermost loops (or branches in general) are also suboptimal for performance. So try to minimize their usage. But I guess in your case there isn't much you can do about it. - Greetings